# I tried to read an excel file and write the same data in another excel in java using Apache POI

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I have to read all the data present in an excel sheet and write the same data in another excel sheet. This has to be done with 2 methods, one for reading the data and the other for creating an excel and writing the data in it.In the code below I can only read the first row of the excel sheet and write it in another excel sheet and not all the rows in the excel sheet. I am not able to find where I have gone wrong.

```
package datareadwrite;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;

public class DataReadandWrite {

public static String[] a = new String[3];

public static void main(String[] args) {
//define an object  
DataReadandWrite dobj = new DataReadandWrite();
//dobj.createsheet();
dobj.readdata();
//System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
dobj.writedata(a);
}   
//Read method       
public String[] readdata() {
    try
{
    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("XlToRead.xlsx"));
    //Create Workbook instance holding reference to .xlsx file
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);     
    //Get first/desired sheet from the workbook
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    //Iterate through each rows one by one
     for (Row row : sheet) {
         //Iterate and get the cells from the row
         Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
         // Loop till you read all the data
         //for (int j=0;j<2;j++) {
         while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
             // 3 is the number of columns
            for(int i=0; i<3;i++) {
              Cell cell = cellIterator.next();                
             switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                 case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                     //System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                     break;
                 case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                     //System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue());*/
         String temp = cell.getStringCellValue();
         a[i]=temp;
                     break;      
             }
         }             
         return a;

     }
     file.close();
     }

}
     catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }
    return null;
}


//Write method
public void writedata (String[] a2) {
//Create a new Workbook
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
//Create a blank sheet
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet(" Data ");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a2));
Object[] datatypes = a2;
int rowNum = 0;
    Row row = sheet.createRow(rowNum++);
    int colNum = 0;
    for (Object field : datatypes) {
        Cell cell = row.createCell(colNum++);
        if (field instanceof String) {
            cell.setCellValue((String) field);
        } else if (field instanceof Integer) {
            cell.setCellValue((Integer) field);
        }
    }


    try{
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File   ("new.xlsx"));
        workbook.write(out);
        out.close();
        System.out.println("writesheet1.xlsx Successfully created");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
   }
}
```

The Code after using a 2D array is below. There will be no data present in the new excel created when I run this code.

```
package datareadwrite;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Row;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
public class DataReadandWrite {

public static String[][] a = new String[3][8];

public static void main(String[] args) {
//define an object  
DataReadandWrite dobj = new DataReadandWrite();
dobj.readdata();
//System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a));
dobj.writedata(a);
}   
//Read method       
public String[][] readdata() {
    try
{
    FileInputStream file = new FileInputStream(new File("XlToRead.xlsx"));
    //Create Workbook instance holding reference to .xlsx file
    XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(file);     
    //Get first/desired sheet from the workbook
    XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    //Iterate through each rows one by one
     for (Row row : sheet) {
         //Iterate and get the cells from the row
         Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = row.cellIterator();
          for(int j=0; j<8;j++) {
         while (cellIterator.hasNext()) {
             // 3 is the number of columns
            for(int i=0; i<3;i++) {
              Cell cell = cellIterator.next();                
             switch (cell.getCellType()) {
                 case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
                     //System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                     break;
                 case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                     //System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue());*/
         String temp = cell.getStringCellValue();
         a[i][j]=temp;
                     break;      
             }
         }             


     }
     file.close();
     }
     }
     }
     catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 } catch (IOException e) {
     e.printStackTrace();
 }
    return a;
}

//Write method
public void writedata (String[][] a2) {
//Create a new Workbook
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
//Create a blank sheet
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet(" Data ");
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(a2));
Object[][] datatypes = a2;
int rowNum = 0;
    Row row = sheet.createRow(rowNum++);
    int colNum = 0;
    for (Object field : datatypes) {
        Cell cell = row.createCell(colNum++);
        if (field instanceof String) {
            cell.setCellValue((String) field);
        } else if (field instanceof Integer) {
            cell.setCellValue((Integer) field);
        }
    }


    try{
        FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(new File ("new.xlsx"));
        workbook.write(out);
        out.close();
        System.out.println("writesheet1.xlsx Successfully created");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: If `String[]` is for one row, then you need to return a 2D array `String[][]`

Comment: @user7 I tried returning a 2D array but that din't work. No values are written in the new excel sheet.

Comment: Please post your latest code then

Comment: @user7 I have added the latest code. please check that.

Comment: `a[i]=temp;` wouldn't even compile

Comment: @user7 Sorry I had not seen that. I have edited it now.